# How to animate an increasing number within an SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

How would I go about making the increase of a number within an `SKLabelNode` animate?

If you have played Clash of Clans you will be familiar with the animation that happens to your totals when you collect either Elixir or Gold.

I.e. when I add 500 to an `Integer` I want to animate the `SKLabelNode` to cycle up quickly through the digits from from 0 to 500. So each time I press the button, the animation occurs.

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

I do a quickly code in playground to guide some light, i don't know if the code work 100%, but the logic is this

```
var timeAnimation = 2;
var coinsLabel:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "0");
var gainCoin = 400;
var currentCoin = 20;

func addCoin(coinTotal:Int)
{
    currentCoin = coinTotal+currentCoin;

    self.runAction(SKAction.customActionWithDuration(timeAnimation, updateLabel));

    func updateLabel(node:SKNode!, t:CGFloat) -> Void{
        let coinToAdd = currentCoin*(t/timeAnimation);
        coinsLabel.text = ""+Int(coinToAdd);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, print out the score as 0. Initialize a variable i (you don't have to call it that) to 0. Then, in the update function, print out the score and increment i. Worked for me.

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
{
   if i <= score
   {
     scoreText.text = "Score \(i)"
     i++
   }
}
```